# How can I delete the objects in Amazon s3 after the objects reaches certain number say 20

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I was trying to delete the objects in my s3 bucket after they reach a certain limit say around 20 objects. I used this code in my Java SDK.

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);

    AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
    String bucketName = "testbucket";
        System.out.println("Listing objects");
        ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest()
        .withBucketName(bucketName);
        ObjectListing objectListing = s3.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);
        int count = 0;
        for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
            count = count + 1;
            if (count < 20)
            {
                System.out.println("Keep Counting");
            }

            else {
                    String key = objectSummary.getKey();
                    s3.deleteObject(bucketName, key);
                }
      }
   }
}
```

But this deletes only those objects which are after the first 20 objects. But, I want all the files to be deleted in s3 once the number of objects in the bucket croses 20+. how would I do that. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bring the check for `size > 20` outside your loop. Also, maximum number of summaries that can be pulled at a time is 1000 - so, you need to check if there are more, pull them and delete them.

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
String bucketName = "testbucket";
System.out.println("Listing objects");
ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(bucketName);
ObjectListing objectListing = s3.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);
int count = 0;
List<S3ObjectSummary> summaries = objectListing.getObjectSummaries();
if(summaries.size() > 20) // Delete only when the size of bucket is > 20
{
    for(;;)
    {
        for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : summaries)
        {
            String key = objectSummary.getKey();
            s3.deleteObject(bucketName, key);
        }
        if(!objectListing.isTruncated())  // Max of 1000 summaries are fetched in 1 pull
        {
            break;
        }
        objectListing = s3.listNextBatchOfObjects(objectListing);
        summaries = objectListing.getObjectSummaries();
    }
}
```